# Which variables should i convert for logistic regression?

Tags: r, regression, logistic

I have the following variables:

```
Income (int) 1 2 3 1 1 1 2 
BodyMass (num) 30.2 26.3 33 34 32.1
EatingTimemain (int) 40 119 60 90 95 110
EatingTime secondary (int) 0 30 30 4 0 32 10 0 0
FizzyDrink (chr) 0 2 1 3 2
Exercise (int) 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 2 2
ExFrequency (chr) 5 4 4 6 0
FastFood (int) 1 2 2 1 2 1 1 2
FastFreq (chr) 0 2 2 1 1 2 2
DietPlan (int) 2 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 2
Obesity (chr) 1 0 0 0 1 1 0
```

I'm trying to fit Exfrequency, FastFreq, FizzyDrink, Eatingtimemain, EatingTime secondary, Dietplan and income into a logistic model with obesity as the response variable. I'm not sure which of the variables I should convert to numeric before applying the model to.

I have done the following code:

```r
lr.model <- glm(obesity ~ Exfrequency + FastFreq + FizzyDrink + 
                          Eatingtimemain + EatingTime secondary + 
                          Dietplan + income, 
                          family = "binomial", data = CHD)
library(car)
pander(vif(lr.model), caption = "VIF factors")
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "should"? You can fit whatever model you want. It just makes a difference in how you interpret the results. There's no one "right" way to do it. If you need statistical advice, you should ask for help at [stats.se] instead. This isn't a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Please include info on what the variables measure and units of measure.  Variables that measures something on a continuous scale, like income, should be numeric, variables with discrete (nominal, ordinal) values, like `Dietplan`, should be factors.